# Doctrine 2: Inversed self referencing entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have following entity:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="zf_categories")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="extend", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $extend;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="extend")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set extend
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\Category $extend
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setExtend(\Application\Entity\Category $extend = null)
    {
        $this->extend = $extend;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get extend
     *
     * @return \Application\Entity\Category 
     */
    public function getExtend()
    {
        return $this->extend;
    }

    /**
     * Add children
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\Category $children
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addChild(\Application\Entity\Category $children)
    {
        $this->children[] = $children;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove children
     *
     * @param \Application\Entity\Category $children
     */
    public function removeChild(\Application\Entity\Category $children)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($children);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }
}
```

Im using code which save data in following format:

```
----------------------
| id | extend | name |
----------------------
| 1  | NULL   | food |
| 2  | 1      | meat |
| 3  | 2      | pork |
----------------------
```

This entity go from 'root' to 'leaf', so when I try:

```
$categories = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => '3'));


foreach($categories->getChildren() as $children)
{
    var_dump($children->getId());
}
```

It doesn't work, that's mean it doesn't display 'children'.
I would like to go from 'leaf' to 'root', so when I have object #3, getChildren() should return me object #2 and so on.

Any tips how to build such entity?

**var_dump($categories->getChildren())**

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[428]
  private 'snapshot' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'owner' => 
    object(Application\Entity\Category)[415]
      private 'id' => int 3
      private 'name' => string 'pork' (length=4)
      private 'extend' => 
        object(DoctrineORMModule\Proxy\__CG__\Application\Entity\Category)[430]
          public '__initializer__' => 
            object(Closure)[417]
              ...
          public '__cloner__' => 
            object(Closure)[418]
              ...
          public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
          private 'id' (Application\Entity\Category) => int 2
          private 'name' (Application\Entity\Category) => null
          private 'extend' (Application\Entity\Category) => null
          private 'children' (Application\Entity\Category) => null
      private 'children' => 
        &object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[428]
  private 'association' => 
    array (size=15)
      'fieldName' => string 'children' (length=8)
      'mappedBy' => string 'extend' (length=6)
      'targetEntity' => string 'Application\Entity\Category' (length=27)
      'cascade' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'orphanRemoval' => boolean false
      'fetch' => int 2
      'type' => int 4
      'inversedBy' => null
      'isOwningSide' => boolean false
      'sourceEntity' => string 'Application\Entity\Category' (length=27)
      'isCascadeRemove' => boolean false
      'isCascadePersist' => boolean false
      'isCascadeRefresh' => boolean false
      'isCascadeMerge' => boolean false
      'isCascadeDetach' => boolean false
  private 'em' => 
    object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[342]
      private 'config' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration)[146]
          protected '_attributes' => 
            array (size=14)
              ...
      private 'conn' => 
        object(Doctrine\DBAL\Connection)[345]
          protected '_conn' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection)[400]
              ...
          protected '_config' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration)[146]
              ...
          protected '_eventManager' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\EventManager)[346]
              ...
          protected '_expr' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Query\Expression\ExpressionBuilder)[347]
              ...
          private '_isConnected' => boolean true
          private '_transactionNestingLevel' => int 0
          private '_transactionIsolationLevel' => int 2
          private '_nestTransactionsWithSavepoints' => null
          private '_params' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
          protected '_platform' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform)[348]
              ...
          protected '_schemaManager' => null
          protected '_driver' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver)[344]
              ...
          private '_isRollbackOnly' => boolean false
          protected 'defaultFetchMode' => int 2
      private 'metadataFactory' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory)[343]
          private 'em' => 
            &object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[342]
          private 'targetPlatform' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform)[348]
              ...
          private 'driver' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain)[150]
              ...
          private 'evm' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\EventManager)[346]
              ...
          protected 'cacheSalt' => string '$CLASSMETADATA' (length=14)
          private 'cacheDriver' (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory) => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache)[149]
              ...
          private 'loadedMetadata' (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory) => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'initialized' => boolean true
          private 'reflectionService' (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory) => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService)[368]
              ...
      private 'unitOfWork' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork)[351]
          private 'identityMap' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'entityIdentifiers' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          private 'originalEntityData' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'entityChangeSets' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'entityStates' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          private 'scheduledForDirtyCheck' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'entityInsertions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'entityUpdates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'extraUpdates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'entityDeletions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'collectionDeletions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'collectionUpdates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'visitedCollections' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            &object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[342]
          private 'commitOrderCalculator' => null
          private 'persisters' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'collectionPersisters' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'evm' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\EventManager)[346]
              ...
          private 'listenersInvoker' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Event\ListenersInvoker)[352]
              ...
          private 'orphanRemovals' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'readOnlyObjects' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'eagerLoadingEntities' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      private 'eventManager' => 
        object(Doctrine\Common\EventManager)[346]
          private '_listeners' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      private 'proxyFactory' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory)[354]
          private 'em' => 
            &object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[342]
          private 'uow' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork)[351]
              ...
          private 'proxyNs' => string 'DoctrineORMModule\Proxy' (length=23)
          private 'metadataFactory' (Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory) => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory)[343]
              ...
          private 'proxyGenerator' (Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory) => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator)[355]
              ...
          private 'autoGenerate' (Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory) => int 1
          private 'definitions' (Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory) => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      private 'repositoryFactory' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory)[350]
          private 'repositoryList' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      private 'expressionBuilder' => null
      private 'closed' => boolean false
      private 'filterCollection' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\FilterCollection)[404]
          private 'config' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration)[146]
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            &object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[342]
          private 'enabledFilters' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'filterHash' => null
          private 'filtersState' => int 1
  private 'backRefFieldName' => string 'extend' (length=6)
  private 'typeClass' => 
    object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[369]
      public 'name' => string 'Application\Entity\Category' (length=27)
      public 'namespace' => string 'Application\Entity' (length=18)
      public 'rootEntityName' => string 'Application\Entity\Category' (length=27)
      public 'customGeneratorDefinition' => null
      public 'customRepositoryClassName' => null
      public 'isMappedSuperclass' => boolean false
      public 'parentClasses' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'subClasses' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'namedQueries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'namedNativeQueries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'sqlResultSetMappings' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'identifier' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'id' (length=2)
      public 'inheritanceType' => int 1
      public 'generatorType' => int 4
      public 'fieldMappings' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          'name' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
      public 'fieldNames' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
      public 'columnNames' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
      public 'discriminatorValue' => null
      public 'discriminatorMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'discriminatorColumn' => null
      public 'table' => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'zf_categories' (length=13)
          'options' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      public 'lifecycleCallbacks' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'entityListeners' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'associationMappings' => 
        array (size=2)
          'extend' => 
            array (size=19)
              ...
          'children' => 
            array (size=15)
              ...
      public 'isIdentifierComposite' => boolean false
      public 'containsForeignIdentifier' => boolean false
      public 'idGenerator' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Id\IdentityGenerator)[389]
          private 'sequenceName' => null
      public 'sequenceGeneratorDefinition' => null
      public 'tableGeneratorDefinition' => null
      public 'changeTrackingPolicy' => int 1
      public 'isVersioned' => null
      public 'versionField' => null
      public 'reflClass' => 
        object(ReflectionClass)[396]
          public 'name' => string 'Application\Entity\Category' (length=27)
      public 'isReadOnly' => boolean false
      protected 'namingStrategy' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultNamingStrategy)[385]
      public 'reflFields' => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[386]
              ...
          'name' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[390]
              ...
          'extend' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[392]
              ...
          'children' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[409]
              ...
      private '_prototype' (Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo) => 
        object(Application\Entity\Category)[410]
          private 'id' => null
          private 'name' => null
          private 'extend' => null
          private 'children' => null
  private 'isDirty' => boolean false
  private 'initialized' => boolean false
  private 'coll' => 
    object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[427]
      private '_elements' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Comment: did you copy your exact code? if so a lot of your annotations are completly broken..

Comment: @SBH No, I didn't copy code. I updated annotations now, just skiped getters and setters, they are generated automatically by doctrine. Didn't add anything to them.

Comment: what does the constructor of the class look like? There should be something like `$this->children = new ArrayCollection();` And what do you get if you `var_dump($categories->getChildren());`?

Comment: @SBH I copied my exact code with all setters, getters, etc. I added also var_dump() response.

Comment: Root to Leaf: use `$node->getChildren()`. Leaf to Root: use `$node->getExtend()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is: How to implement an Entity that behaves like a tree?

#### Recursion

One option is to use [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). You implement a function that creates a list while it loops over the children of a node. If a child is a leaf it creates an entry in the list, if the child has children of its own, it calls itself (this creating a new list, etc, etc).

Because Doctrine 2 will lazy-load the association (children), this setup can become problematic when the tree of nodes grows larger, especially when it gets more and more levels. You can end up performing countless of queries to load the entire tree.

#### Nested Set

A [Nested Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) model doesn't form a tree by storing the parent of a node, but by storing left/right ordering numbers and depth. This enables you to fetch the entire tree of a arbitrary node with just a single query.

The [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) library can help you setup and use entities that follow the Nested Set model, read about its [Tree extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md). If you're using Symfony 2, there's [a bundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) to integrate this library. If you're using Zend Framework 2, you can read how to integrate it [here](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/zendframework2.md).

#### Which to choose

Recursion is very efficient for insert/update operations, it is very inefficient for read (select) operations.

Nested set is efficient for read operations, it's even efficient for update operations, but inefficient for insert operations.

When you have more inserts than reads/updates, go for Recursion. But when you have more reads/updates than inserts, so go for Nested Set.

Answer (score 0):

Following code should help you to go from 'leaf' to 'root'.

```
$category = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Category')->find(3);
 $this->recursive($category);

...

public function recursive(Category $category)
{
    if($category->getExtend()==null){
        return;
    }

    echo $category->getName();
    $this->recursive($category->getExtend());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help me, becouse I have to find a way to go from leaf to root

Comment: I have edited my answer now it goes from leaf to root.